# Why Does CodeIgniter 3 give me these error?

Tags: codeigniter-3

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: Creation of dynamic property CI_URI::$config is deprecated

Filename: core/URI.php

Line Number: 102

Backtrace:

File: D:\Workspace\htdocs\codeigniter\property\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

How To solve This CodeIgniter 3 Framework? Please huehuehue

i dunno how to fix these error and what line of code what am i gonna fix im waiting for your answers ! Developers And Engineers

Im new to codeigniter 3 Thanks for answering my concerns i aprecciated:)

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75122968/3960296